# Mysql query for displaying image in category order

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display category wise one image in the view,but the below query collects all the category images collectively and displays each category items as the hole.

```
SELECT *  
                        FROM (
                          (SELECT *, 
                                 IF( @prev <> category_id, 
                                     @rownum := 1, 
                                     @rownum := @rownum+1 
                                 ) AS rank, 
                                 @prev := category_id, 
                                 @rownum  
                          FROM (
                            SELECT * FROM products 
                            ORDER BY category_id, rand()
                          ) random_prodcts)
                        ) products_ranked 
                        WHERE rank <= 20000 AND parent_category_id = 3;
```

I  want this query to be modified and display each category item as one until all the items are displayed one by one at a cycle.

**This is the table structure.**

```
Id  Parent_category_id  Category_id Product_position
1         3                    77   00
2         3                    77   00
3         3                    78   00
4         3                    78   00
5         3                    89   00
6         3                    89   00
```

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding the specification. (What is an `item`? What do you mean by "each category item", and "one by one at a cycle"?)  An *example* of the expected result set would help explain the requirement. (Is the query shown returning the rows you need, but you need them in a different order? (The query looks way more complicated than it needs to be, and we don't see anything here that initializes `@prev` and `@rownum` on the first execution.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need rows returned in a particular order, then add an `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

For example, if you want to return all the rows with a `rank` of 1 first, then something like:

```
 SELECT r.*
   FROM ( 
          SELECT @rownum := IF(@prev = r.category_id, @rownum+1, 1) AS rank
               , p.id
               , p.parent_category_id
               , @prev := p.category_id AS category_id
               , p.product_position
            FROM products p
           CROSS
            JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rownum := 0) i
           ORDER
              BY p.category_id
               , RAND()
        ) r
 WHERE r.parent_category_id = 3
   AND r.rank <= 20000
  ORDER
     BY r.rank
      , r.category_id
```

---

I'm not understanding why the equality predicate on the `parent_category_id`  column is in the *outer* query, and not in the inner view query. If `parent_category_id` is dependent on `category_id` (the sample data doesn't show an example of a `category_id` value that is associated with more than one `parent_category_id`), then I don't see any reason it couldn't be relocated, for potentially better performance, by reducing the number or rows that need to be materialized into the inline view, and reducing the number of calls to the `RAND()` function, and reducing the size of the set that needs to be sorted.

Comment: I need to display items on category wise,So I gave parent_category _id as range from 1 - 7 and category_id from 1 to 85,the thing is if it returns with parent_category_id=3 then it have several items as same like element five alone will arrive at many times,it displays that 5 category element alone at ascending order. But I  need a cyclic retrieval of record like (3,5)(3,6)(3,7)and again like (3,5),(3,6)(3,7)... And so on.